# python openssl does not support sha256

Tags: python, openssl

system : centos .

I update my python(to 3.10) and openssl(to 1.1.1t), then my database connector(pymongo) give me an error:

```
salted_pass = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(digest, data, standard_b64decode(salt), iterations)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256.
```

and i run this(my old code):

```
hmac.new("AAA".encode('utf-8'), "BBB".encode('utf-8'),'SHA256').hexdigest()
```

i recompile python again ,this time i did't compile openssl, then i found i can run above code. but i can't use ssl module...

confuse me all day.

---

Answer (score 0):

Oh, fine! i solve this problem. before you compile your python.
set this file : $PythonSourceDir$/Modules/Setup ,line 211

[image]

Comment: Or u can use --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl3 --with-openssl-rpath=auto ,this two command